# Changing keyboard navigation panel in ubuntu

Tags: gnome, keyboard, top-bar, navigation

I use ubuntu with gnome DE. On clicking <kbd>Alt</kbd> on my keyboard, a keyboard navigation panel opens between the application window(of almost any application in full screen) and the top-bar from where I can perform various tasks using the arrows and keys of keyboard.

Is there any way I can shift this control panel such that it opens in the top bar on clicking <kbd>Alt</kbd> rather than creating space between the window and the top-bar, which looks quiet jerky?